# Python splitting string to find specific content

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to split a string in python to extract a particular part. I am able to get the part of the string before the symbol `<` but how do i get the bit after? e.g. the `emailaddress` part?

```
 >>> s = 'texttexttextblahblah <emailaddress>'
 >>> s = s[:s.find('<')]
 >>> print s
```

This above code gives the output `texttexttextblahblah`

Comment: may be will be more correctly: s = s[s.find('<')+1:]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s[s.find('<')+1:-1]
```

or

```
s = s.split('<')[1][:-1]
```

Comment: Cheers. Works perfectly. Yeah nothing will ever follow the > in my data.

Answer (score 1):

cha0site's and ig0774's answers are pretty straightforward for this case, but it would probably help you to learn [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for times when it's not so simple.

```
import re
fullString = 'texttexttextblahblah <emailaddress>'
m = re.match(r'(\S+) <(\S+)>', fullString)
part1 = m.group(1)
part2 = m.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps being a bit more explicit with a regex isn't a bad idea in this case:

```
import re
match = re.search("""
    (?<=<)  # Make sure the match starts after a <
    [^<>]*  # Match any number of characters except angle brackets""", 
    subject, re.VERBOSE)
if match:
    result = match.group()
```